# Having PHP files inside a AngularJS app directory?

Tags: php, angularjs, database

I wanted to connect my MySQL database, perform some data operation and display the formatted data using AngularJS. Since Angular uses only REST API calls, I have written a separate PHP for DB connection and converting the resultant data to JSON format.

I'm wondering what is the best place(practice) to keep my PHP files inside app directory or is there any other way to perform this operation.

FYI, I have AngularJS app and Backend DB on same machine.

Comment: This all depends on how you want to do things really but I typically have a php folder next to my app folder rather than inside of it.  You could also just have a completely separate repo for the PHP side of things if you prefer but best IMO to keep them somewhat separated so you have your API and then you have your client code and they don't mix.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Hope I will keep a separate PHP directory outside app directory